# php / sql code inside php function not working

Tags: php

I have a certain PHP & MySQL code. 
the code works fine when its not inside a PHP function, code is below:

```
require'connection.php';

$sql = "SELECT name_english FROM team";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0)  {
       // output data of each row
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          echo $row[name_english];
      }
}
```

when I use the same exact code but inside a PHP function and call 
the function at the end of the file, it does not work.

Comment: Show your code that doesn't work

Comment: variable scope issue, look that up

Comment: May be your connection `$conn` is not visible in the scope of function. If that's the case then either use `global $conn;` or pass the connection handler `$conn` to your function.

Comment: So... You're showing us code that works, and asking us why some *other*, *different* code doesn't work?  How exactly do you expect us to be able to help with that?

Comment: $row[name_english] to $row['name_english']

Comment: David .. its the same exact code .. i just put it inside a php function . any way thanks a lot  it works now the problem was in the connection .

Comment: @AhmedMaged: I'm not sure what you *think* the term "same exact" means, but when you modify something *in any way* (such as putting it in a different contextual block of code) then it becomes "different".  When code isn't working, usually it's a good idea to look at the code.  Not to look at other, unrelated code.

Answer (score 1):

For a start please read about **PDO**: http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.connections.php
When you must **get access** to element in associative array you must send **name of variable**. In this case you send VARIABLE `name_english` that contains the name of a variable. if you want get acess to element `name_english` you *must put* in quotes (**'name'**).

```
echo $row[name_english];
```

**To:**

```
echo $row['name_english'];
```